# Play Framework: How to route to a HTML page in the public folder

Tags: playframework, routes

Here below is my application layout:

```
myapp
  + app
  + conf
  + modules
  |   + mymodule
  |       + app
  |       + conf
  |       + public
  |           + swagger-ui
  |                + css
  |                + images
  |                + index.html
  + public
  + ...
```

I want to load `index.html` with url `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui`... and here below are my routes in `modules/mymodule/conf/mymodule.routes`:

```
...

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET /assets/*file       controllers.mymodule.Assets.at(path = "/public", file)
GET /swagger-ui         controllers.mymodule.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
```

The routes above work... except that the resources (images, css) referenced by `index.html` are not found. If I modify the routes like this...

```
...

GET /assets/*file       controllers.mymodule.Assets.at(path = "/public", file)
GET /swagger-ui/*file   controllers.mymodule.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

... then it works as expected and referenced resources are also loaded... but of course I need to provide an url like `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/index.html`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How are the CSS/Images referenced in the index.html file?

Comment: They are referenced like this: images/logo.png, css/screen.css, etc.

Comment: What is an example 404 error URL?

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:9000/api-docs/css/highlight.default.css instead of http://localhost:9000/api-docs/swagger-ui/css/highlight.default.css...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried what James suggested – and in my opinion was the solution that made more sense...

```
GET     /swagger-ui         controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET     /swagger-ui/*file   controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

... but actually it only worked partially, i.e. `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui` was correctly routed to `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/index.html`, but then all the relative paths contained in it (e.g. `css/highlight.default.css`) were routed to `http://localhost/mymodule/css/*` instead of to `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/css/*`. That said, to make it work I had to modify the routes like this:

```
GET     /swagger-ui         controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET     /*file              controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

The routes above work as expected

1. `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui` is routed to `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/index.html`
2. `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/index.html` is not routed at all, hiding `index.html` to end users
3. Relative paths in `index.html` are routed to `http://localhost/mymodule/swagger-ui/css/*`

I hope that helps.

Comment: Whats the difference between your first routes segment and your second?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: "That said, to make it work I had to modify the routes like this:"

I thought I was missing a character, but I did a string compare of the two routes file examples above and they are identical. What's the difference?

Comment: Where are they identical?
[GET     /swagger-ui         controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html"),
GET     /*file              controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)].
The first one maps /swagger-ui to index.html, while the second one mpas any other file to the corresponding file in the swagger-ui directory.

Comment: I'm not talking about the individual lines, I'm talking about these two code segments: http://i.imgur.com/znJvwb2.png

Comment: Ah OK... it was just a typo - it's fixed now. The first routes segment just shows what James suggested, while the second segment shows the solution that actually works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
GET /swagger-ui         controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET /swagger-ui/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

(Order matters)

Comment: No... same result as before. My be it is worth to say that the routes are part of a play sub-project - see my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a redirect first like this

```
GET     /swagger-ui          controllers.Default.redirect(to = "swagger-ui/")
GET     /swagger-ui/         controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET     /swagger-ui/*file              controllers.apidocs.Assets.at(path = "/public/swagger-ui", file)
```

If you browse to /swagger-ui it will redirect to swagger-ui/ so the next calls to js, css and images will be in the correct path